# Making a lambda expression to call a method from a generic class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda, expression-trees, func

I have these simple interface:

```
public interface IQuery<TResult> { }

public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, out TResult> 
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult> {
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

And there are some implementation of them. I'm trying to create an expression-tree to call `Handle` method on a specified handler. I mean:

```
var query = new MyQuery(); // which MyQuery implements IQuery<int>
object handler = _someServiceProvider
    .Get<IQueryHandler<MyQuery, int>>();
```

Also, there is a `MyQueryHandler`:

```
public class MyQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<MyQuery, int> {
    public int Handle(MyQuery query) { return 20; }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to create a `Func<object, MyQuery, int>` to call like this:

```
var func = GetMethod<MyQuery, int>(handler);
var result = func(handler, query);
```

And here is my `GetMethod` implementation:

```
    private Func<object, TQuery, TResult> GetMethod<TQuery, TResult>(object obj)
        where TQuery : IQuery<TResult> {

        var methodInfo = obj.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>.Handle));

        var insExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "ins");

        var inputExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TQuery), "query");

        var instanceExp = Expression.Variable(obj.GetType(), "instance");

        var assExp = Expression.Assign(instanceExp, Expression.Convert(insExp, obj.GetType()));

        var castExp = Expression.Convert(inputExp, methodInfo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType);

        var callExp = Expression.Call(instanceExp, methodInfo, castExp);

        var blockExp = Expression.Block(new Expression[] {
            insExp,
            inputExp,
            instanceExp,
            assExp,
            castExp,
            callExp
        });

        var func =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<object, TQuery, TResult>>(
                blockExp,
                insExp,
                inputExp).Compile();
        return func;
    }
```

But, when I try to compile `Lambda`, I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: variable 'instance' of type
>   'Namespace.MyQueryHandler' referenced from scope '', but it is not
>   defined

Where am I wrong? What I missed? Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need to merge expression-trees to this? it seems like overcomplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to write this function:

```
TResult f(object ins, TQuery query)
{
    var instance = (MyQueryHandler)ins;
    return instance.Handle(query);
}
```

To do this using expression trees, you have to declare the variable in your `Expression.Block`, but then only specify the two statements above, not all subexpressions:

```
var blockExp = Expression.Block(new[] { instanceExp }, new Expression[] {
    assExp,
    callExp
});
```

But a simpler option would be to write the following function instead:

```
TResult f(object ins, TQuery query)
{
    return ((MyQueryHandler)ins).Handle(query);
}
```

That would look like this:

```
var callExp = Expression.Call(
    Expression.Convert(insExp, obj.GetType()), methodInfo, castExp);

var func =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<object, TQuery, TResult>>(
        callExp,
        insExp,
        inputExp).Compile();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got that. But question: what's `Dump()` here and what does it do? Also, this is a red code ):

Comment: @Javad_Amiry Dump is likely because svick was using [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to debug. Just remove it.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry David_G is right, I forgot to remove that before posting.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you are trying to do with your expression in `GetMethod`, so I will not use it and write completely from scratch.

If you want to pass both handler and query to your method - you don't need to pass any instances to `GetMethod`:

```
private static Func<object, TQuery, TResult> GetMethod<TQuery, TResult>()
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult> {
    // "query" paramter
    var query = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TQuery), "query");
    // "handler" parameter
    var handler = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "handler");
    // convert your "object" parameter to handler type (not type safe of course)
    // ((IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>) handler).Handle(query)
    var body = Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(handler, typeof(IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>)), "Handle", new Type[0], query);
    //(handler, query) => ((IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>) handler).Handle(query);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, TQuery, TResult>>(body, handler, query).Compile();
}

object handler = new MyQueryHandler();
var func = GetMethod<MyQuery, int>();
var result = func(handler, query);
```

If you *do* pass `handler` instance to `GetMethod` - you don't need to later pass that same instance again to your created `func` - you can reuse the same instance like this (assuming that fits your scenario of course):

```
private static Func<TQuery, TResult> GetMethod<TQuery, TResult>(object obj)
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult> {
    // parameter
    var query = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TQuery), "query");
    // note Expression.Constant here - you use the same instance for every call
    var body = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(obj), "Handle", new Type[0], query);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TQuery, TResult>>(body, query).Compile();
}
```

And use it:

```
var query = new MyQuery(); // which MyQuery implements IQuery<int>
object handler = new MyQueryHandler();
var func = GetMethod<MyQuery, int>(handler);
var result = func(query);
```

Comment: Thank you :) I used svick's answer.

Comment: That's fine, but note that you don't need to pass instance of your handler to the method just to get reference to `Handle`, so your `GetMethod` can be without parameters (feels better to not pass useless parameters as for me).

Comment: Agreed. I changed the parameter from being an `instance` to be a `obj.GetType()`. cause, you would need to know what's the type of current instance and cannot use `typeof(IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>)`. But thanks again. Cheers.